# it is possible to use the table-sm class with datatables?

Tags: html, datatables

I've been trying to implement DataTables into my web site, I'm using Bootstrap 4 styling.

This is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="dataTable_wrapper table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover display compact table-sm" id="TblDetalleComision">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                    <th>Col3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to wrap the table with CSS?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

give tbody to class "table-sm" Like

```html
<tbody class="table-sm"></tbody>
```

It worked for me